# Pandas condition on dates

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to calculate tenure in months variable as of '2019-12-31'.

for this, I create a new column LatestEmploymentDate (type datetime64[ns]) which is by default '2019-12-31' if they didn't quit. If the employee's employment has ended, then the value would be EmploymentEndDate (type datetime64[ns])

```
df_employee1['LatestEmploymentDate'] = pd.to_datetime('2019-12-31')
df_employee1.loc[df_employee1['LatestEmploymentDate'] != pd.to_datetime('2019-12-31'), 'LatestEmploymentDate'] \
= df_employee1['EmploymentEndDate']
print(df_employee1[['LatestEmploymentDate','EmploymentEndDate'] ])
```

Here is the print results

```
   LatestEmploymentDate EmploymentEndDate
0              2019-12-31               NaT
1              2019-12-31               NaT
2              2019-12-31        2019-03-08
3              2019-12-31               NaT
4              2019-12-31               NaT
...                   ...               ...
1996           2019-12-31        2019-12-17
1997           2019-12-31               NaT
1998           2019-12-31               NaT
1999           2019-12-31               NaT
2000           2019-12-31               NaT
```

The LatestEmploymentDate is not equal to EmploymentEndDate when it is populated. Can someone tell me what is wrong with my logic?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your mask `df_employee1['LatestEmploymentDate'] != pd.to_datetime('2019-12-31')` will be wholly False. So you're not assigning anything to it.

Comment: @Zenvega I have modified the code and also added result for your reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
df_employee1['LatestEmploymentDate'] = pd.to_datetime('2019-12-31')
df_employee1.loc[df_employee1['EmploymentEndDate'].isna()!=True, 'LatestEmploymentDate'] = df_employee1['EmploymentEndDate']
print(df_employee1[['LatestEmploymentDate','EmploymentEndDate'] ])
```

[image: Result]

Comment: LatestEmploymentDate EmploymentEndDate
0                     NaT               NaT
1                     NaT               NaT
2              2019-03-08        2019-03-08
3                     NaT               NaT
4                     NaT               NaT
...                   ...               ...
1996           2019-12-17        2019-12-17
1997                  NaT               NaT
1998                  NaT               NaT
1999                  NaT               NaT
2000                  NaT               NaT

Comment: I am not able to format the table properly here.

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of the result?

Comment: You cannot check for equality on NaN/NaT types. Try `pd.NaT == pd.NaT` and check for yourself.

Comment: @FelipeLanza I think 'is not pd.NaT' will work. Because 'pd.NaT is pd.NaT' returns True

Comment: True. But you really should just use `pd.isna` to check this

Comment: How to check is not na condition?

Comment: Just do `pd.isna(some_series)`. In your case you are essentially checking if a `Series` is `pd.NaT`. It makes no sense.

Comment: @FelipeLanza I just negated the result of .isna()!=True and this works fine